# SQL server procedure transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

i am executing the below  stored procedure concurrently

```html
i am executing the below  stored procedure concurrently 
create procedure test @a
AS
if(@a=0)
begin
delete from tab1
insert into tab1
select * from tab2
end
else
begin
delete from tab1 where id=@a
insert into tab1
select * from tab2 where id=@a
end
```

In the above in tab2 id is primary key
table tab1 has no duplicate records.
when i am executing the above sp concurrently in different sessions
exec test 0
exec test 1
i am getting duplicate error.
It is executing as follows

```
Delete(test 0) delete(test 1)   insert(test 1) Insert  (test 0)
```

I want to execute it as

```
Delete(test 0) insert(test 0)   delete(test 1) Insert  (test 1)
```

or

```
Delete(test 1) insert(test 1)   delete(test 0) Insert  (test 0)
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a transaction (begin tran, commit tran) around the delete + insert. That should fix the issue. For more complex things you'll probably need to adjust isolation level.